# 1TB ext. HDD suddenly stops working - does not show up on desktop - Lion OS X

Tags: external-hard-drive, osx-lion, hard-drive-recovery

I'm really annoyed right now. I brought this 1TB external HDD (brand: WD elements) about 3-4 days ago. I put two partitions onto it, one Mac journal partition (for Mac) and one for PC to be able to be read, however, it has just stopped working now!

If I plug in the HDD via USB, the two partitions does not show up on my desktop, nor anything that relates to the HDD, now I went to Disk Utility to check, I can see both partitions on the application, recently I verified the disk, it said it was corrupt and needs repairing, so I thought WTF? I went ahead and repaired the disk, it took roughly 4 hours to do so (I only have 9GB worth of files at the moment on the HDD).

After that, an error message was saying that the disk did not eject properly -- I did not do anything, I did not pull off the USB or switch off the HDD.

Problem is, I have very important files on the HDD which I really, really, *really* need to recover and get it back...

I restarted my Mac recently too, then I unplugged my HDD and plugged it back in, nothing still shows up! The HDD was again appearing in Disk Utility, but one of the partitions has been renamed which was the Mac partition, it has been renamed to `disk1s1` and I don't know why... The other partition has not been renamed.

If I go to Terminal and go to `/Volumes`, I can only see my MacBook HDD. All I need is to be able to get back the files I have stored on my HDD asap in an effective and loss-proof method then I have no idea what to do next except to format the HDD all over again. I really need help with this.

EDIT: I've just again verified the disk, it told me to repair it (again).

[image]

EDIT #2: I saw both partitions on the desktop, I opened up the Mac partition and went to copy all the files to the desktop, but the transfer speed was so slow (10KB/s at least) and only transferred every 10~ seconds (10-30KB). `Finder.app` suddenly froze and then I had to relaunch `Finder.app`. I cannot see the two partitions again in the desktop and I ejected the HDD from Disk Utility and re-plugged the USB and now I get this:

[image]

In Disk Utility I cannot do anything else, the two partitions does not show in Disk Utility:

[image]

Also, I cannot repair it whatsoever, please... I have no idea what to do and I'm real annoyed with this!

EDIT #3: Just tried to erase/format the HDD, it cannot proceed:

[image]

Comment: Return it and get a new one. It's broken. It happens.

Comment: After 3 days of purchase... damn...

Comment: You could try the other USB port. Maybe it's your computer. But other than that, either the controller or the disk itself have problems, as indicated by that last screenshot (and the rest of your post, really). Since it's a bundle product, you shouldn't care which of the components it is, and just replace it.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just in contact with the seller, I'm returning it. Cheers.